# Enabling uClinux to run on Altera DE2-115?

Tags: fpga, linux, computers, intel-fpga, quartus-ii

I'm trying to learn Qsys and Quartus II to define a system that can run linux according to this document:

http://uuoc.org/uClinux_nios2_custom_hardware.pdf

But I'm running into problem as the document is not detailed enough. I get errors from Qsys and Quartus and I'm not exactly sure whether I'm doing the right thing.

[image]

[image]

I tried to add the SDRAm but I was not successful, could you please help me understand how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you drop the components into QSYS, click the little dots in the 'Connections' column to wire them together. The grey outlines will go black once the connections are made and the errors will be cleared.

You will be greatly aided by completing the Qsys tutorials available at Altera.com, support section, search for `OQSYS1000`.